# Python googlesearch API - change country location and get Ads results

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-search, google-search-api

I'm trying to use the googlesearch api in Python to get the top 10 results for several queries, and I'm encountering two issues:

1. Changing the country using the 'country' param (e.g country='us' etc..) doesn't seem to have any affect on the results at all. Tried this with several countries.
2. I want to include the Ads results and can't find any way to do so.

If anyone knows how to do this with googlesearch or any other free API that would be great.

Thanks!

```
# coding: utf-8
from googlesearch import search
from urlparse import urlparse
import csv
import datetime

keywords = [
    "best website builder"
]
countries = [
  "us",
  "il"
]

filename = 'google_results.csv'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')

  for country in countries:
    for keyword in keywords:
      print "Showing results for: '" + keyword + "'"
      writer.writerow([])
      writer.writerow([keyword])
      for url in search(keyword, lang='en', stop=10, country=country):
        print(urlparse(url).netloc)
        print(url)
        writer.writerow([urlparse(url).netloc, url])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer 1. Your country format is incorrect.

What the module is doing is building the URL to make the request. With the following format:

`url_search = "https://www.google.%(tld)s/search?hl=%(lang)s&q=%(query)s&btnG=Google+Search&tbs=%(tbs)s&safe=%(safe)s&cr=%(country)s"`

When you give it a country, simply passing in `us` or `il` is not enough. You want the country parameter to be in the format of `countryXX` where XX is the two letter abbreviation. For example France is `FR`. So country will be `countryFR`.

And even in the source code it say that this parameter is not always reliable.

```
    :param str country: Country or region to focus the search on. Similar to
        changing the TLD, but does not yield exactly the same results.
        Only Google knows why...
```

Answer 2: Ads are dynamically loaded using JavaScript. This library on the other hand only does static parsing. It does not execute any of the JavaScript. You will need to run Selenium or pyppeteer to have the browser execute the JavaScript to get the ads.

Comment: This works well for most countries, but using `country = "countryUS"` and variations upon that returns result in my country of origin. Is there any other code for the United States?

Comment: The code did mention that the results are not always the same. It could just be that you are making the request from an IP address that isn't from the United States.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the country targeting parameter is just a signal to Google, not a setting change. Google will not actually show you the results as they appear to an anonymous user in that country. So it's basically useless.

The APIs mentioned above will not fix this either as they only use US based IP addresses. (@Link can you confirm? I'd pay for your API if it wasn't only on US servers.)

So you're going to actually need to run this code from a server with an IP address in the country you're targeting, with the browser settings params of the country language set too.

You won't be able to render the ads either, as they're rendered slightly after the fact separately. There is a huge industry trying to get this right, and anyone who has nailed it charges pretty high fees. But the best place to start would be on an IP address in that country and using selenium. Requests won't cut it, and certainly not if you want ads.

Finally, Google is super aggressive with automated search detection as every search you automate that shows an ad, skews their advertiser numbers and actually costs advertisers money, even if you don't click on them (due to a mechanism called quality score).

If your volume is low, selenium based script with a private IP (as in, not an AWS or Azure data center ip) in that country is your best bet.

And if you figure out how to do this at scale, you'll have people falling over themselves to get the solution.